# Java JNA: JRE crashes after application completes

Tags: java, jna, jvm-crash

I'm accessing a native lib with JNA. This is my first time ever working with JNA and I also don't have experience with c/c++. I was able to get the application to work and I get a correct result returned and displayed using `System.out.println()`. This is the last line of my code. The value is displayed in console and then Java crashes, eg. the dialog `Java Platform SE binary has stopped working` is displayed with option to close or debug.

The console then shows this:

`Java Result: -1073741819`

Windows Event viewer says 0xc0000005 which according to existing answers is a me

**EDIT 5 21th August 2018:**

This has still not been solved and now I'm looking into it again. What was solved was the issues with MemoryError when looping. Since I really need a solution now I also stop obfuscating the dll. AFAIK the supplier it out of business. They don't reply to questions and the web site is outdated.

My "documentation" comes from [here](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/76682-error-c2664-trying-call-external-dll.html)

Here the current java code:

```
public interface CLogP extends StdCallLibrary {
    CLogP INSTANCE = (CLogP) Native.loadLibrary("BB-CLOGP", CLogP.class);
    NativeLong calcLogP(String smiles, FloatByReference logP, NativeLongByReference numContrb, HANDLEByReference contrib);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //contrib can also be a PointerByReference, the behaviour is the same
    HANDLEByReference contrib = new HANDLEByReference();
    FloatByReference cLogP = new FloatByReference();
    NativeLongByReference numContrib = new NativeLongByReference();
    NativeLong err = CLogP.INSTANCE.calcLogP("c1ccccc1", cLogP, numContrib, contrib);
    System.out.println(err.intValue());
    System.out.println(cLogP.getValue());
    System.out.println(numContrib.getValue());
    //needs to be done after ever call to calcLogP
    //then no issue running in a loop
    Kernel32.INSTANCE.GlobalFree(contrib.getValue().getPointer());
    // Tried to free other variables, does not have any effect
    //Kernel32.INSTANCE.GlobalFree(cLogP.getPointer());
    //Kernel32.INSTANCE.GlobalFree(numContrib.getPointer());
}
```

I'm kind of lost. Above works with an outdated version of the dll but not with the newest one. What's going wrong? Would disassembling it help in any way?

**OLD CODE and INFO**, only partially relevant now:

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FloatByReference result = new FloatByReference();
    //EDIT: changed to NativeLongByReference as per suggested answer
    NativeLongByReference numContrib = new NativeLongByReference();     
    // This is a struct that needs to be passed by reference
    MyDll.PContribution.ByReference contrib = new MyDll.PContribution.ByReference();        
    NativeLong err = MyDll.INSTANCE.calcResult("myValue", result, numContrib, contrib);
    // I only care about result and not the other out-parameters
    System.out.println(result.getValue());
    //crash here
}
```

Defintion of the function in c:

`typedef long (CALCRESULT)(const char*, float*, long*, HANDLE*);`

What is going wrong? Do I need to perform some cleanup before the application terminates?

EDIT:

I can run the method call in a loop and it works. It only ever crashed when it terminates.

EDIT2:

As per comment here code for MyDll:

```
public interface MyDll extends Library {

    public static class PContribution extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends PContribution implements Structure.ByReference {

                public byte[] Class = new byte[10];
                public byte[] Type = new byte[6];
                public byte[] Description = new byte[40];
                public byte[] Comment = new byte[10];
                public float Value;
        }
            protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
                    return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Class", "Type", "Description", "Comment", "Value" });
                }
}

    MyDll INSTANCE = (MyDll) Native.loadLibrary("MyDll", MyDll.class);

    NativeLong calcResult(String smi, FloatByReference result, NativeLongByReference numContrb, PContribution contrib);
}
```

Definition of the `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    char Class[10];
    char Type[6];
    char Description[40];
    char Comment[10];
    float Value;
} PContribution;
```

**EDIT 3:**

Damn. I figured out that the available documentation is for an old version of the dll. Using the old dll, everything works. So now I need to get docs of new version from supplier.

**EDIT 4:**

It works with old dll but the app consistently crashes after 65533 iterations (calls). Each call uses exactly the same parameters.

```
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:390)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:323)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:236)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.calcLogP(Unknown Source)
```

The whole point of the exercise is to be able to make thousands of calls quickly.

Comment: Please also post your class definition for `MyDll`.  The declaration for `calcResult()` is relevant here.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See edits. I can't create a runable example as I can't share the dll.

Comment: I had figured the problem may be in the dll.  Updating my answer to be a bit more verbose about probable causes.

Comment: The `ByReference` on the `Structure` is superfluous.  Passing `Structure` as a parameter implies `struct*` semantics by default.

Comment: Try turning off garbage collection.  If that resolves the issue, then you have a problem with memory being freed during object finalization.

Comment: The 65533 is very suspicious, as 65535 is the max 16-bit number.  Is there some resource that you are reserving that you have to release when calling your function?    Hard to know without the API!

Comment: Yeah, thought so as well. I do not use a 16-bit number in my code. I also tried with recreating all function parameters in the loop and the issue still happens. Could this be an issue with the library or JNA itself? API / function is `typedef long (CALCRESULT)(const char*, float*, long*, HANDLE*);`

Comment: Why do you use the `PContribution` structure when the function signature uses `HANDLE`?  Do you need to [close the HANDLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Or is it a [HANDLEByReference](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinNT.HANDLEByReference.html)?  Either way, try closing it...

Answer (score 1):

The Java result you get is an error message. -1073741819 is 0xc0000005, which is the code for STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION: you're accessing memory that you don't have permissions for.

The fact that it's occurring when your application closes indicates that it's associated with object finalization, which occurs when your program terminates and could also occur when garbage collection is triggered.  It is likely that Java/JNA is attempting to release memory that C has not allocated.

When you get this sort of error you should investigate:

- Type mapping from C to JNA (particularly object size)
- Memory allocation mismatches Java vs. C (which side is allocating the memory)
- Releasing resources/memory allocated on the C side by your API (handles, references, ports, etc.)

**Type Mapping**

A comparison of your code vs. the c function definition shows two mismatches.

- The CALCRESULT function has a pointer to a `long` in C.  Whether this is a 32-bit or 64-bit long is [operating system dependent](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/size-of-long-integer-type-on-different-architecture-and-os) while Java's `long` is always 64-bit.  You should map native `long` values to JNA's [NativeLong](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/NativeLong.html) type.  While this might not be causing the crash in this case, it is vitally important to know this distinction when the value is inside an array or a structure because it will throw off the byte offsets. As a pointer to a native `long`, your variable `numContrib` should therefore be of type [NativeLongByReference](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/ptr/NativeLongByReference.html)
- The CALCRESULT function has a pointer to the `HANDLE` type in C, but you pass a structure (by reference).  A few notes here:

  - I'm not sure why you have to use ByReference.  When you pass a structure as an argument like this, JNA turns it into the pointer for you, and takes care of allocating and releasing memory, and auto-reading the native memory into the structure for you.  So in general you wouldn't pass a structure by reference.  (Personally, I like to avoid ByReference structures, and just manipulate a `Pointer` directly, creating a new Structure using that Pointer.  Probably the same thing but it's more clear to me what's happening.)
  - The C method specifies a pointer the specific Windows type `HANDLE`. A [Handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724457(v=vs.85).aspx) is a reference to an internally maintained table that has access to other system resources, etc.  Handles should be released when you are done using them, or you tie up those resources.  JNA models the `HANDLE` type; in this case you have a pointer so the appropriate type would probably be a [HANDLEByReference](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinNT.HANDLEByReference.html).

**Memory allocation mismatches**

It's unclear why you are using a structure when the API provides you a pointer to a `HANDLE` type (JNA `HANDLEByReference`).  Java allocates the necessary memory when you define a `new` instance of the structure (In your case the `PContribution`) and JNA will map that Java memory to the local memory for you.  However, the C function is giving a pointer to the `HANDLE` type which takes up less memory than the structure you've defined.  It's entirely possible that when Java is freeing up the structure memory on the Java side and then trying to release the same memory on the C side, it's running into problems because it's telling C to release more memory (for the structure) than C allocated (for the HANDLE).   Answering further about this is not possible without more clear documentation from your API on how you get from this HANDLE to the structure you have listed in its place.

**Releasing resources**

Since the API is using the `HANDLE` type it's likely other resources than memory are involved, and you have a responsibility to release those references.  See the [CloseHandle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx) function. Whether you have to close the handle yourself with this function, or whether the API will close it for you with one of its own methods implementing `CloseHandle()` internall should be clearly documented in the API (in this case for the CALCRESULT function). Without the API to inspect I can't help much further, but carefully read the documentation to see if any of the structures you create in your code are required to be explicitly freed / released, and how.

Comment: I'm on 32-bit windows. I made the changes but the same issue happens. In fact for both cases I can call `numContrib.getValue()` and the value is fine and application does not crash when calling it. Maybe the issue is with the `struct`. See my edits.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Pay close attention to when/where memory is allocated for the structure.  Why is it ByReference?

Comment: Native long is identical in size on win32 and win64 (always 32 bits).

Comment: Removing ByReference had no impact. It works with old dll (up to a certain point, crashes after roughly 70k iterations with `Invalid memory access`, same with new dll) and JRE still crashes using new dll.

Comment: Given the function declaration with type `*HANDLE` it may be that a `HANDLEByReference` is the correct type.  I don't understand where your structure comes from or how the API tells you to get from the handle in the method to your structure.  Also, typically a HANDLE needs to be closed/released, so I'd really focus your troubleshooting here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Problem is I do not have any documentation (just 1 search hit from google). I've contacted the supplier of the dll. Issue is it's supplied by an application from a different supplier which itself licenses the dll. I will wait and see if I get any feedback from them. I also tried with `HANDLEByReference` and also using `Kernel32.CloseHandle()` or `Kernel32.GlobalFree()` as the limited doc I have indicates but the issue remains the same.