# How to close Karate.robot session running on windows machine, getting some thread error

Tags: karate

I had a question regarding karate.robot do we have any method or function to shut down or close or quit Karate.robot session like driver. quit or close?
it seems some threads are occupied getting following error many times:
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000065a03e06, pid=11236,
tid=8836
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64
compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x4c3e06]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions
of Windows
#

```
[thread 6836 also had an error]

[.error occurred during error reporting , id 0xc0000005]

#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Dll Process Attached
Loading jawt.dll
Dll Process Detach

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: just made one more edit to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we don't see a need. You typically start the `Robot` instance and it stays up until the end of your entire suite. Maybe you should try install the JDK 64-bit or 32-bit.

You are welcome to contribute code to improve anything if required. So far no one has reported any problems like this. Maybe you are trying to do things in parallel threads which is not supported. Provide a way to replicate if you can: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

EDIT - one area you can help us investigate is if we need to do more to release JNA resources after a `Scenario` in [this method](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/v1.1.0/karate-robot/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/robot/win/WinRobot.java#L68).

Also see this answer: [Java JNA: JRE crashes after application completes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37678424/143475)

Comment: Thanks, The problem got resolved after installing the JDK.  Ran multiple times, did not get this error. If I get this error again then I will investigate.